# How to map docker ip adress to Domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tomcat

Right now, I am setting up the AWS server with tomcat docker.

I am successfully map with Domain name provided by Namecheap but unfortunately, my website still can access by the public ip address.

I want to redirect the ip address to domain name.

I tried set the hosts file but it did not work.

For example, 127.0.0.1 www.abc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the instance public IP in your Domain provider setting, not the local IP of Docker.

- Publish docker port to host `docker run -dit -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT your_image`
- Allow port in the security group of instance
- update DNS to point to the public IP address of the instance

**Update:**

You need to run Nginx in your EC2 machine, then add following config in the Nginx config.

Try this on the second block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name YOUR_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP;

    return 301 $scheme://www.abc.com$request_uri;
}
```

redirect `127.0.0.1` to  `www.abc.com` not possible, as `127.0.0.1` is local IP and not accessible from outside of EC2.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work as I wanted. I want the public ip address when accessing the website redirect to the domain name automatically. I could not do it with AWS and none of solution on the internet works.

Comment: oh I thought you want to access Docker form outisde of ec2? but you want to redirect IP to domain which does not make sense

Comment: Actually, this solution works but I faced an issue while setting up the nginx and tomcat server up because these two are running on same port 80. Anything I could do to make it out without change tomcat to other port? Thanks mate

Comment: if you running nginx in container then you use `docker run -it -p 8080:80 nginx` if out side follow this https://www.tecmint.com/change-nginx-port-in-linux/

Comment: Acutally, the problem is that, I am using nginx listen to port 80 and I want my tomcat run on the same port 80 as well. So, by doing this way, when user visits my website without seeing the port number. I tried change default port of nginx to other but I checked the port using, nginx still using that port number. Sorry, this is my first time using nginx.

Comment: you check the link i provided or you can ask new question

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 0):

expose the docker container port:

docker run --name awsContainer -p 80:8080

-p 80(port aws instance):8080(tomcat container port)